req.sessionID changes for every subsequent HTTP request
On the client-side in React, I used axios to make HTTP requests from localhost:5173 to the server side on localhost:3000. I used the express-session and connect-session-sequelize libraries and configured the session as follows:
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(config["database"], config["username"], config["password"], {
    dialect: "mysql",
    storage: "./session.sqlite",
  })

  app.use(express.json())
  app.use(cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: 'http://localhost:5173'
  }))
  var myStore = new SequelizeStore({
    db: sequelize,
    checkExpirationInterval: 15 * 60 * 1000, // The interval at which to cleanup expired sessions in milliseconds.
    expiration: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
  });
  app.use(
    session({
      secret: "keyboard cat",
      store: myStore,
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      cookie: {
        maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 24 hours
        secure: false,
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'none'
      },
    })
  );
  await myStore.sync()

From React, I sent an HTTP POST request to the http://localhost:3000/auth/login backend
    axios.post("http://localhost:3000/auth/login", newUser, { withCredentials: true })

The backend receives it and outputs the request session ID
req.session.userId = findUsername.id
req.session.save(() => ... res.json({...}) ...)
console.log(`Request session ID: ${req.sessionID}`)


But after I reroute to http://localhost:3000/getRegister using the following axios line:
axios.post("http://localhost:3000/auth/register", newUser, { withCredentials: true } 
the request sessionID changes. And I also don't see the new userId field
Interestingly enough, if I send a subsequent post request to http://localhost:3000/auth/login again, sessionId is the same as last time

I'm not sure how it worked but I did
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
In each file that uses import axios
